# Counts the total number of rows in the table MYSQL SPRING

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mybatis

I am trying to count all the number of rows in my Mysql table using Spring, Mybatis and Thymeleaf framework. I have a data sheet like this:
Table: user

```
  id name
  1 John
  2 Jack
  3 William
  4 Harry
```

I want to count all the rows in the user table or get the maximum value in the table (here is 4), I use the select statement in the service class:
UserService.java

```
@Select ("Select count (id) from user)
List <User> countById ();
```

Implemented in Controller class

UserController.java

```
modelAndView.addObjects ("user", userService.countById ());
```

And display it outside of the HTML
user.html

```
<div>
<span th: text = "$ {user.id}> </span>
</div>
```

The page displays error, I don't know I'm wrong with Service, Controller or HTML. I want the output to show as 4. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Select annotation should be changed to @Query annotation, also the return type of the method should be long.

This should work:

```
@Query("SELECT count(u.id) FROM user u)
long countById ();
```

and in view part you can output it such as below:

```
<div>
<span th: text = "${user}> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Select change to `@Query`, you can read more about writing query from this blog: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: The OP asked about MyBatis - not JPA. So the annotation should stay `@Select`. Other then that, the rest of this answer is on the right track.